# Is it possible to statically predict when to deallocate memory---from source code only?

Tags: parsing, memory

Memory (and resource locks) are returned to the OS at deterministic points during a program's execution. The control flow of a program by itself is enough to know where, for sure, a given resource can be deallocated. Just like how a human programmer knows where to write `fclose(file)` when the program is done with it.

GCs solve this by figuring it out directly during runtime when the control flow is executed. But the real source of truth about the control flow is the source. So theoretically, it should be possible to determine where to insert the `free()` calls before compilation by analyzing the source (or AST).

Reference counting is an obvious way to implement this, but it's easy to encounter situations where pointers are still referenced (still in scope) yet no longer needed. This just converts the responsibility of manually deallocating pointers to a responsibility to manually manage the scope/references to those pointers.

It seems like it's possible to write a program that can read a program's source and:

1. predict all the permutations of the program's control flow---to similar accuracy as watching the live execution of the program
2. track all the references to allocated resources
3. for each reference, traverse the whole subsequent control flow in order to find the earliest point that the reference is guaranteed to never be dereferenced
4. at that point, insert a deallocation statement at that line of source code

Is there anything out there that does this already? I don't think Rust or C++ smart pointers/RAII is the same thing.

Comment: look up the halting problem. It's the grandfather of why the question of "Can't a compiler figure out if a program does X?" is always answered with "Not in the general case."

Comment: _Memory (and resource locks) are returned to the OS at deterministic points during a program's execution._ No.

Comment: @Euphoric How else do you the programmer know when to deallocate? It would be very difficult to do that as a machine, no doubt, but there has to be a way I think...

Comment: @ratchetfreak Thanks, it's not ever knowing stuff like this halting problem that makes me wish I got my degree in comp sci instead of chemistry.

Comment: @zelcon5, you now know about chemistry *and* the halting problem... :)

Comment: @zelcon5 They don't. Generally. Its usually only educated guess when dealocation should happen. It is why lots of non-GC software has memory leaks and tools for finding them exist.

Comment: @Euphoric unless you structure your program so the boundaries of when a resource is used is very clear like with RAII or try-with-resources

Comment: @ratchetfreak While that is nice in theory, in practice, it becomes "Halting problem for humans".

Comment: The problem is that the programmer knows when a resource is no longer needed because the programmer decides that a resource is no longer needed. That may be enforced using design rules, such as closing the only GUI window that a user could possibly use to access that resource (or, in many cases, it may be accidentally _not enforced at all_ — hence program crashes exist). But there is no general way for a compiler to understand these enforcements; at least, not with today's technology.

Comment: I invite you to attempt to "predict all executions of control flow" of, say, a compiler. All you have to do is predict the behaviour of the compiler on **every possible program, legal or illegal, that could possibly be fed into it** and verify that for all of that literally infinite set of possibilities, memory is not leaked.  Now do you see why this is a harder problem than you make it out to be?

Comment: This isn't possible to do in the general case. Rust takes an interesting path though, because it forbids a lot of things that are legal in other languages (e.g. C, C++, C#, Java) and it appends more compile-time information (e.g. lifetimes as generic arguments). By doing these, instead of having to solve the lifetime problem for the general case, Rust forces you to express everything through a few specific special cases that have well known incoming and outgoing requirements to the compiler. (Which I think is a good direction for languages that want no tracing GC and no dangling pointers.)

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet I think it's important to note that *programmers get this wrong too*. That's one of the motivations to turning to GC in the first place. As soon as you make any resource shared, you're in trouble - and for a human, it's easy to forget to release local resources as well. Sure, you did it right 500 times, but that 501th slipped - that's simply the kind of errors humans make all the time. And that's just when writing the code for the first time - a lot of memory bugs are introduced with "unrelated" code changes, or even auto-merge issues :)

Comment: @Luaan: I pretty much said that :P

Comment: RAII is a convenient acronym but a better name for it is Scope-Based Resource Management (SBRM). The key point is that when the scope terminates, the resource is indeed guaranteed to be released. Scope can be checked by the compiler. Of course, a scope that never terminates, such as a server waiting indefinitely for incoming requests, or a halting-problem example, wouldn't release the resource; that doesn't violate the promise of SBRM. Also, one can implement scope-based GC on top of SBRM; they aren't incompatible.

Comment: What if the program you're analyzing is itself a programming language interpreter? Your analyzer now needs to automatically write a garbage collection feature for that interpreter.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Take this (contrived) example:

```c
void* resource1;
void* resource2;

while(true){

    int input = getInputFromUser();

    switch(input){
        case 1: resource1 = malloc(500); break;
        case 2: resource2 = resource1; break;
        case 3: useResource(resource1); useResource(resource2); break;
    }
}
```

When should free be called? before malloc and assign to `resource1` we can't because it might be copied to `resource2`, before assigning to `resource2` we can't because we may have gotten 2 from the user twice without a intervening 1.

The only way to be sure is to test resource1 and resource2 to see if they are not equal in cases 1 and 2 and free the old value if they were not. This is essentially reference counting where you know there are only 2 possible references.

Comment: Actually that's not the only way; the other way is to only _allow_ one copy to exist. This, of course, comes with its own problems.

Answer (score 28):

RAII is not automatically the same thing, but it has the same effect. It provides an easy answer to the question "how do you know when this cannot be accessed any more?" by using *scope* to cover the area when a particular resource is being used.

You might want to consider the similar problem "how can I know my program will not suffer a type error at runtime?". The solution to this is *not* predicting all the execution paths through the program but by using a system of type annotation and inference to prove that there cannot be such an error. Rust is an attempt to extend this proof property to memory allocation.

It is possible to write proofs about program behaviour without having to solve the halting problem, but only if you use annotations of some kind to constrain the program. See also security proofs (sel4 etc.)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36727/discussion-on-answer-by-pjc50-is-it-possible-to-statically-predict-when-to-deall).

Answer (score 12):

Yes, this exists in the wild. [The ML Kit](http://www.elsman.com/mlkit/) is a production-quality compiler that has the described strategy (more or less) as one of its available memory management options. It also allows for the use of a conventional GC or hybridizing with reference counting (you can use a heap profiler to see which strategy will actually produce the best results for your program).

[A retrospective on region-based memory management](http://www.elsman.com/pdf/retro.pdf) is an article by the original authors of the ML Kit that goes into its successes and failures. The eventual conclusion is that the strategy is practical when writing with the assistance of a heap profiler.

(This is a good illustration of why you shouldn't usually look to the Halting Problem for an answer to practical engineering questions: we don't *want or need* to solve the general case for most realistic programs.)

Comment: I think this is an excellent example of proper application of the Halting Problem.  The halting problem tells us that the problem is unsolvable in the general case, so you look for limited scenarios in which the problem is solvable.

Comment: Note that the problem becomes far *more* solvable when we talk about pure or nearly pure functional, non-side-effecting languages like Standard ML and Haskell

Answer (score 10):

> predict all the permutations of the program's control flow

This is where the problem lies. The amount of permutations is so huge (in practice it is infinite) for any non-trivial program, that time and memory needed would make this completely impractical.

Comment: good point. I guess quantum processors are the only hope, if there's any at all

Comment: @zelcon5 Haha, no. Quantum computing makes this *worse*, not better. It adds additional ("hidden") variables to the program and much more uncertainty. Most practical QC code I've seen relies on "quantum for fast computation, classical for confirmation". I've barely scratched the surface on quantum computing myself, but it seems to me that quantum computers may not be very useful without classical computers to back them up and check their results.

Answer (score 8):

The halting problem proves this isn't possible in all cases.  However, it is still possible in a great many cases, and in fact, is done by nearly all compilers for probably a majority of variables.  This is how a compiler can tell it's safe to merely allocate a variable on the stack or even a register, instead of to longer-term heap storage.

If you have pure functions or really good ownership semantics, you can extend that static analysis further, although it becomes prohibitively more costly to do so the more branches your code takes.

Comment: Well, the compiler *thinks* it can free the memory; but it may not be so. Think of the common beginner's error to return a pointer or a reference to a local variable. The trivial cases are caught by the compiler, true; the less trivial ones aren't.

Comment: That mistake is made by *programmers* in languages where *programmers* must manually manage memory allocation @Peter.  When the *compiler* manages memory allocation, those sorts of mistakes don't happen.

Comment: Well, you made a very general statement including the phrase "nearly all compilers" which must include C compilers.

Comment: C compilers use it to determine what temporary variables can be allocated to registers.

Answer (score 4):

If a single programmer or team writes the whole program, it is reasonable that design points can be identified where memory (and other resources) should be freed.  Thus, yes, static analysis of the design may be sufficient in more limited contexts.

However, when you factor in third party DLLs, APIs, frameworks, (and throw in threads, too), it can be very difficult (nay, impossible in all cases) for the using programmers to correctly reason about what entity owns what memory and when the last use of it is.  Our usual suspect of languages don't sufficiently document the transfer of memory ownership of objects and arrays, shallow and deep.  If a programmer can't reason over that (statically or dynamically!) then a compiler most likely can't either.  Again, this is due to the fact that memory ownership transfers are not captured in method calls or by interfaces, etc.., so, no it is not possible to statically predict when or where in the code to release memory.

As this is such a serious problem, many modern languages choose garbage collection, which automatically reclaims memory sometime after last live reference.  GC has a significant performance cost (especially for real-time applications), however, so is not a universal cure all.  Further, you can still have memory leaks using GC (e.g. a collection that only grows).  Still, this is a good solution for most programming exercises.

There are some alternatives (some emerging).

The Rust language takes RAII to an extreme.  It provides linguistic constructs that define the transfer of ownership in methods of classes and interfaces in more detail, e.g. objects being transferred-to vs. borrowed-by between a caller and callee, or in longer lifetime objects.  It provides a high level of compile time safety toward memory management.  However, it is not a trivial language to pick up, and is also not without it's problems (e.g. I don't think the design is fully stable, certain things are still being experimented with, and thus, changing).

Swift and Objective-C go yet another route, which is mostly-automatic reference counting.  Reference counting gets into issues with cycles, and, there are significant programmer challenges, for example, especially with closures.

Comment: Sure, GC has costs, but it also has performance benefits. For example, on .NET, allocating from the heap is almost free, because it uses the "stack-allocation" pattern - just increment a pointer, and that's it. I've seen applications that run faster rewritten around the .NET GC than they've been using manual memory allocation, it really isn't clear cut. Similarly, reference counting is actually quite expensive (just at different places from a GC), and something you don't want to pay if you can avoid it. If you want real-time performance, static allocation is often still the only way.

Answer (score 3):

Freeing of memory, in general, is equivalent to the halting problem - if you can't statically tell whether a program will halt (statically), you can't tell whether it will free memory (statically) either.

```
function foo(int a) {
    void *p = malloc(1);
    ... do something which may, or may not, halt ...
    free(p);
}
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem

That said, Rust is very nice...
https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ownership.html

Answer (score 2):

If a program does not depend on any unknown input then yes, it should be possible (with the caveat that it may be a complex task and may take long; but that would be true for the program as well). Such programs would be completely solvable at compile time; in C++ terms, they could be (almost) completely composed of `constexpr`s. Simple examples would be to compute the first 100 digits of pi or to sort a known dictionary.