# Are Python mixins an anti-pattern?

Tags: object-oriented, python, inheritance, python-3.x, mixins

I'm fully aware that `pylint` and other static analysis tools are not all-knowing, and sometimes their advice must be disobeyed. (This applies for various classes of messages, not just `convention`s.)

---

If I have classes like

```
class related_methods():

    def a_method(self):
        self.stack.function(self.my_var)

class more_methods():

    def b_method(self):
        self.otherfunc()

class implement_methods(related_methods, more_methods):

    def __init__(self):
        self.stack  = some()
        self.my_var = other()

    def otherfunc(self):
        self.a_method()
```

Obviously, that's contrived. [Here's a better example, if you like](https://github.com/catb0t/simpleforth/blob/HEAD@%7B2016-03-10%7D/forth.py#L212).

I believe this style is called using "mixins".

Like other tools, `pylint` rates this code at `-21.67 / 10`, primarily because it thinks `more_methods` and `related_methods` don't have `self` or attributes `otherfunc`, `stack`, annd `my_var` because without running the code, it apparently can't see `related_methods` and `more_methods` are mixed-in to `implement_methods`.

[Compilers and static analysis tools can't always solve the Halting Problem](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/311972), but I feel this is certainly a case in which looking at what's inherited by `implement_methods` would show this is perfectly valid, and that would be a very easy thing to do.

Why do static analysis tools reject this valid (I think) OOP pattern?

Either:

1. They don't even *try* to check inheritance or
2. mixins are discouraged in idiomatic, readable Python

---

#1 is obviously incorrect because if I ask `pylint` to tell me about a class of mine that inherits `unittest.TestCase` that uses  `self.assertEqual`, (something defined only in `unittest.TestCase`), it does *not* complain.

Are mixins unpythonic or discouraged?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Mixins just aren't a use case that was considered by the tool.  That doesn't mean it's necessarily a bad use case, just an uncommon one for python.

Whether mixins are used appropriately in a particular instance is another matter.  The mixin anti-pattern I see most frequently is using mixins when there is only ever intended to be one combination mixed.  That's just a roundabout way to hide a god class.  If you can't think of a reason *right now* to swap out or leave out one of the mixins, it shouldn't be a mixin.

Comment: yeah, it's a god object, I admit. In this case I'd argue it's OK for the CPU to be a god object.

Answer (score 23):

I believe that Mixins can, absolutely, be Pythonic. However, the idiomatic way to silence your linter--and improve your Mixins' readability--is to both (1) define [abstract methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html) that explicitly define the methods that a Mixin's children are required to implement, and to (2) pre-define `None`-valued fields for Mixin data members that children must initialize.

Applying this pattern to your example:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class related_methods():
    my_var = None
    stack = None

    def a_method(self):
        self.stack.function(self.my_var)


class more_methods(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def otherfunc(self):
        pass

    def b_method(self):
        self.otherfunc()


class implement_methods(related_methods, more_methods):
    def __init__(self):
        self.stack  = some()
        self.my_var = other()

    def otherfunc(self):
        self.a_method()
```

Comment: +1 for your answer, although the `abstract other(self): pass` thing trades the linter's confusion for mine

Comment: It's even more confusing without the @abstractmethod ;-)  I started with Java first so this is just fine for me.

Comment: One important fact to allow mixin be Pythonic (from the maintenable facet) is to refuse inheritance in mixins. Initialization with mixins is MRO dependant, and if a root ancestor don't call `super().__init__` the chain is broken.

Comment: @gdoumenc Could you elaborate that a bit?

Answer (score 16):

The linter is not aware that you use a class as a mixin. Pylint is aware that you use a mixin if you add the suffix 'mixin' or 'Mixin' at the end of the class name, then the linter stops complaining.

[image: linter_without_mixins]
[image: linter2_with_mixin]

Mixins aren't bad or good per se, are just a tool. You make them a good use or a bad use.

Comment: Would it be better to declare the fields from subclasses that are needed by the mixin?

Comment: Actually, is there a way to declare abstract fields? This would properly force their implementation.

Answer (score 12):

*I think* mixins can be good, but I also think pylint is right in this case. Disclaimer: opinion-based stuff follows.

A good class, mixins included, has one clear responsibility. Ideally, a mixin should carry all the state it is going to access, and the logic to handle it. E.g. a good mixin could add a `last_updated` field to an ORM model class, provide logic for setting it, and methods to search for the oldest / newest record.

Referring to undeclared instance members (variables and methods) does look a bit weird.

The right approach very much depends on the task at hand.

It may be a mixin with the relevant bit of state kept in it.

It may be a different class hierarchy where the methods that you currently distribute via a mixin are in a base class, while lower-level implementation differences belong to subclasses. This looks most fit for your case with the stack operations.

It may be a class decorator that adds a method or two; this usually makes sense when you have to pass some arguments to the decorator to affect the method generation.

State your problem, explain your bigger design concerns, then we could argue if something is an anti-pattern in your case.

Answer (score 2):

## Are mixins ok?

> Are Python mixins an anti-pattern?

Mixins are not discouraged - they are a good use-case for multiple inheritance.

## Why is your linter complaining?

Pylint is obviously complaining because it doesn't know where the `otherfunc`, `stack`, and `my_var`  is coming from.

## Trivial?

There is no immediately apparent good reason for you separate these two methods into separate parent classes, either in your example in the question, or in your more trivial linked example, shown here.

```
201
202 class OpCore():
203     # nothing runs without these
204
205 class OpLogik(): 
206     # logic methods... 
207 
208 class OpString(): 
209     # string things
210 
211 
212 class Stack(OpCore, OpLogik, OpString): 
213 
214     "the mixin mixer of the above mixins"
```

## Costs of mixins and noise

The costs of what you are doing is making your linter report noise. That noise may obscure more important problems with you code. This is an important cost to weigh. Another cost is that you're separating your inter-related code into different namespaces that may make it harder for programmers to discover the meaning of.

## Conclusion

Inheritance allows for code reuse. If you get code reuse with your mixins, great, they've created value for you that probably outweighs the possible other costs. If you're not getting code reuse/deduplication of lines of code, you're probably not getting much value for your mixins, and at that point, I think the cost of the noise is greater than the benefits.

Comment: There's a good reason for seprating them in the linked, nontrivial example -- it's easier for me to organise my code when I have a fraction of a full class that implements math, another that implements strings, and so on, and you mix them together to get Forth Soup.

Comment: "Another cost is that you're separating your code into different namespaces that may make it harder for programmers to discover the meaning of" -- no, that's not the case at all. The class namespaces make it easier to tell what a group of methods do, and when someone wants to use the stack, they should call / implement the Forth Soup, not the individual ingredients

Comment: @cat probably because they're contrived and not used in a real large project, neither example really supports your points of using mixins. Both show only one time the mixin is used, in which case just putting the implementation in one place is better style and organization. Now if you could show a case where you want common features across classes but do not want a common base class, that's where you'd use a mixin. Which is beside your linting question (UltraBird answered that well). But this answers your question generally regarding mixin applicability.